# How to add tags when saving an object in an Algolia index using the Java API

Tags: java, algolia

The Algolia docs don't show how to use the Java API to save an object with tags.

How does one do this?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: @Michael the Algolia API docs omit info on how to do this in Java, but do show how to do it in Ruby. I've scoured the relevant Java docs and found no mention of tags. I've found nothing that I can try.

Comment: Then maybe including the link to the Ruby section would be helpful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer, it seems, is that you need to do something not so Java-like in the class that represents your Algolia search objects.

You need a _tags field in your Search item object defined as `List<String> _tags`, with corresponding `void set_tags(List<String> tags)` and `List<String> get_tags()` methods.